# Unity missing "Regenerate project files"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image]

I'm having issues with Visual Studio Code recognizing Unity commands.  After looking things a solution is changing my external script editor to visual studio itself.  Problem is in all the videos I'm watching it should look like this

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: vs code doesnt use project files like vsstudio, so no it wont have that option

Comment: Seems you did Install and select the bundled version of VS that comes with the Unity installer ... Never used this tbh .. Try and install VS the normal way and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

To get the external tools page to recognize VSCode(the blue one) and have the Regen Project Files Option , you must configure it.

here are the instructions:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

As you can see the important part is you should remove the package that says VSCode Editor and update your Visual Studio Editor package to at least 2.0.20.

If you need a video on this process, I've made one
https://youtu.be/4KhjzVHQvrg

Things got updated abit since the, so in the video remove the VSCode package was skipped but do so..

Also if you have troubles after following all the steps make sure you actually have newest .NET sdk installed as well.

Goodluck!